# how to delete grid view row on link button click event which is in repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application where I am having one grid view control and one repeater control.When I click on the link button in any row of grid view,then data in repeater control get visible.and in repeater control I am having one delete request link button inside a repeater control.when i will click on this button that particular row in grid view should get deleted.So,how I can do this?
Please suggest me any solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a new application? If so I think you should know that ASP.Net Forms is pretty much dead. I would recommend getting away from it and using ASP.Net MVC instead.

Comment: Post the markup for the repeater and the grid. It's not completely clear (at least to me) what you are asking.

Comment: post ur markup code here.